# Generating a sql query in php using for loop

Tags: php, mysql

**CODE :**

```
 $nerd_result = mysql_query("select * from nerd_profile where nerd_reg_no = '$reg_no'");
$nerd_data = mysql_fetch_array($nerd_result);
$tags = array();
$tags = explode(",",$nerd_data['nerd_interests']);
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($tags)-1; $i++)
{
    if($i != sizeof($tags)-2)
    {
    $sub_query = $sub_query."`tags` like %".$tags[$i]."% or "; 
    }
    else 
    {
        $sub_query = $sub_query."`tags` like %".$tags[$i]."% ";
    }
}



 $proper_query = "select * from `qas_posts` where ".$sub_query." and `post_date` like '%$today%'";
 $result = mysql_query($proper_query);
 while($each_qas = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

**Description :**

I am adding the like clause along with php variable in a string and concatenating it with the further variables with like clause to come. In the end when I echo I get the perfect query that I want but

```
mysql_fetch_array()
```

does not accept that generated query rather if I hard code it , it works perfect what am I doing wrong ?? can I do that ??

Comment: This `%".$tags[$i]."%` needs to be this `'%".$tags[$i]."%'`. You're missing quotes. Also, it's typically a good idea to initialize your variables, e.g. `$sub_query = "";`.

Comment: ohh my goodness .... the quotes... why didn't I see that ... I have been looking on the internet for an hour now .. Thanks :)

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing string comparisons in mysql you need to make sure you have quotes around your comparison value.

```
$sub_query = $sub_query."`tags` like '%".$tags[$i]."%' or ";
```

and

```
$sub_query = $sub_query."`tags` like '%".$tags[$i]."%' ";
```